# Isn't this language in $\mathrm{P}^{\mathrm{NP}}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

For an undirected graph $G$, let us denote $\gamma(G)$ the chromatic number of $G$. Let us define for positive integer $n$, the language 
$$
L_n = \{\langle G\rangle : \gamma(G) = n\}. 
$$
This is the language of undirected graphs with chromatic number $n$. 
I think $L_n \in \mathrm{P}^{\mathrm{NP}}$, for any $n$.

My argument is the following. We can look at the language,
$$
\mathrm{CHROMNUM} = \{\langle G, k\rangle : \gamma(G) \leq k\}. 
$$
It is clear that $\mathrm{CHROMNUM} \in \mathrm{NP}$, since we can verify an instance just by displaying an at most $k$-coloring of $G$.

Thus, consider oracle Turing machine $M^{\mathrm{CHROMNUM}}_n$, which on input $G$, simply checks that $\langle G, n \rangle \in 
\mathrm{CHROMNUM}$ and that $\langle G, k \rangle \not \in \mathrm{CHROMNUM}$ for all $k \leq n$.

I've just read about $\mathrm{P}^{\mathrm{NP}}$, so I wanted to be sure that this kind of argument is correct.

Comment: In fact, you get the same complexity even if $n$ is a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, your argument is correct.**

$\textbf{P}^\textbf{NP}$ is the class of problems which are Cook-reducible (i.e., polynomial-time [Turing-reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction)) to $\textbf{NP}$. A Turing reduction to $\textbf{NP}$ is simply a reduction with oracle access to a problem in $\textbf{NP}$, in this case the problem $\text{CHROMNUM}$.

In fact, using your reasoning and the fact that $\langle G, k \rangle \not\in \text{CHROMNUM} \implies \langle G, k' \rangle \not\in \text{CHROMNUM}$ for all $k' \le k$, you can prove that you only need *two* oracle queries (independent of $n$). That is, your reduction resumes to checking the following:
$$\langle G, n \rangle \in \text{CHROMNUM} \land \langle G, n - 1 \rangle \not\in \text{CHROMNUM}$$
This means you only need *one* $\textbf{NP}$ query and *one* $\textbf{coNP}$ query (since checking if something is not in an $\textbf{NP}$ language is in $\textbf{coNP}$). As it turns out, there is a class of problems which are characterized by having the same type of reduction, the [difference polynomial time](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dp) class $\textbf{D}^\textbf{P}$, and which, incidentally, coincides with the second level of the [Boolean hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bh).